# How to turn off Squid forward mode?

Tags: squid

I'm running Squid in transparent mode but I don't want users to use it for forward mode.

Right now, users can plug-in my proxy IP into their browser and use it like a normal proxy if they are on the ACL allow list.

Is there any way to turn this off and only allow transparent mode?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: firewall off access to the squid port from anything other than whatever's redirecting traffic from port 80 to your squid box.  I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to encourage as much caching as possible, though...